# How can I test a Backbone subclass in Mocha without duplicating tests for the superclass?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, oop, backbone.js, mocha.js

Say I have a couple of Backbone models, Rectangle and Triangle, that each extend Polygon.

```js
var Polygon = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
       width: 100,
       height: 100,
       rotation: 0
    },
    rotate: function (degrees) {
       var oldRotation = this.get('rotation');
       var newRotation = (oldRotation + degrees) % 360;
       this.set('rotation', newRotation);
       return newRotation;
    }
});

var Rectangle = Polygon.extend({
    area: function (degrees) {
      return this.get('width') * this.get('height');
    }
});

var Triangle = Polygon.extend({
    area: function (degrees) {
      return this.get('width') * this.get('height') / 2;
    }
}
```

I want to test Rectangle and Triangle and ensure that each of them independently implements `rotate` correctly, even though I know that (for now) they both inherit the implementation of `rotate` from Polygon.

What I don't want to do is create separate unit tests for Rectangle and Triangle that are almost exact duplicates of one another. In Mocha, how can I write a test for `rotate` and reuse it in the unit tests for both Triangle and Rectangle?

Here are my unit tests. Note the duplicate 'rotates by 45 degrees' test.

```js
describe('A rectangle', function () {
  var r = new Rectangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});
  it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
    expect(r.area()).to.equal(500);
  });
  it('rotates by 45 degrees', function () {
    expect(r.rotate(45)).to.equal(135);
  });
});

describe('A triangle', function () {
  var t = new Triangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});
  it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
    expect(t.area()).to.equal(250);
  });
  it('rotates by 45 degrees', function () {
    expect(t.rotate(45)).to.equal(135);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to re-test `rotate()` when it has not changed in the sub class? You may limit `rotate()` tests to the tests of `Polygon`.

Comment: The idea is that a Polygon has certain invariants, tests that should always pass no matter which subclass of Polygon is being tested. In the future, Triangle may implement the `rotate()` method to add some functionality. I want to ensure the invariants for `Polygon.rotate()` are still satisfied by `Triangle.rotate()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obvious after writing it out. We can create a function to encapsulate the tests for a polygon.

```
var describeAPolygon = function (name, p) {
    describe(name, function () {        
      it('rotates by 45 degrees', function () {
        expect(p.rotate(45)).to.equal(135);
      });
    });
};
```

And then use it in the tests for Rectangle and Triangle.

```
describe('A rectangle', function () {
    var r = new Rectangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});
    describeAPolygon('A rectangle', r);
    it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
      expect(r.area()).to.equal(500);
    });
});


describe('A triangle', function () {
    var t = new Triangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});
    describeAPolygon('A triangle', t);
    it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
      expect(t.area()).to.equal(250);
    });
});
```

That's the cleanest solution I've been able to find. I'm curious if anyone else has tackled this problem and come up with something different.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is :

```
describe('A rectangle', function () {
    var r = new Rectangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});

    it('should be a polygon', function() {
      expect(r).to.be.an.instanceof(Polygon);
    });

    it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
      expect(r.area()).to.equal(500);
    });
});

describe('A triangle', function () {
    var t = new Triangle({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});               

    it('should be a polygon', function() {
      expect(r).to.be.an.instanceof(Polygon);
    });

    it('correctly calculates its area', function () {
      expect(t.area()).to.equal(250);
    });
});

describe('A polygon', function() { 
    var p = new Polygon({width: 50, height: 10, rotation: 90});
    it('rotates by 45 degrees', function () {
      expect(p.rotate(45)).to.equal(135);
    });
});
```

If you use proper OOP practices, your `Polygon` class should have it's methods and structure safe enough to rely that any class that extends it should not be able to modify it.

Comment: Thanks. Now let's suppose we add another method, cutInHalf(), which returns two new polygons. Triangle and Rectangle will each implement cutInHalf() differently. But I still want to test that the areas of the two resulting polygons add up to the area of the original polygon, no matter which type of polygon was split.

Comment: Well in this case, there's nothing wrong to repeat your `expect(a.area() + b.area()).to.equal(c.area());` if `a`, `b` are the split polygons and `c` is the original one. Take a look at how ThreeJS is testing it. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/test/unit/math/Triangle.js

IMHO tests should be 1. readable, 2. fast, but if that's not the case for you, you can reduce code duplication with your method.